# Problem with do while loop that jumps out despite false condition

Tags: c#

Newbie here! I've run into problems with some inconsistency when running the do while loop which surrounds the Try/Catch block.

Messing back and forth with different inputting makes the loop jump out despite its condition, which at multiple occasions should be true and run the block once again. Instead it ends up at "Number already exists" random number of times. It's obviously a hickup somewhere... Am I using it in the wrong way?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];          
        int input = 0;                          
        int numRangeMin = 1;                    
        int numRangeMax = 25;
        bool duplicateNumber = false;
        bool loop = true;

        Console.WriteLine("\n Fill in a number:");

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.Write(" {0}: ", i + 1);
                        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        duplicateNumber = numbers.Contains(input); // Check if number already has been entered
                        loop = false;
                    }
                    catch (System.FormatException)
                    { Console.WriteLine(" Only integers between {0}-{1} Try again!\n", numRangeMin, numRangeMax); }

                    catch (System.OverflowException)
                    { Console.WriteLine(" Number is too big! Enter a number between {0}-{1}\n", numRangeMin, numRangeMax); }

                } while (loop == true);

                // Report if we attempt to insert a duplicate.
                if (duplicateNumber)
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("Number already exists");
                }
                else if (input > numRangeMax)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Too large:\n", numRangeMin, numRangeMax);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            while (duplicateNumber == true); // Keep asking while we don't get a unique number.

            numbers[i] = input; // Store the number
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on **every** line of code. Step through it, line by line. Before the line executes ask yourself "what do I expect this to do?" Then run the line of code. At some point - your expectation won't meet reality. That is where your bug is. Welcome to the lovely art of debugging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loop` variable is defined outside the outer `do` loop, so it will retain it's value whenever you change it, that will lead to the inner loop not to be executed after the first time it has been set as false.

Define `loop` in side the outer loop or set it to `true` prior to the execution of the inner loop.

```
 //...

 do
 {

     loop = true;

     do
     {
         try
         {

         //...
```

Also, the same will happen with the `duplicateNumber` variable because it's declared outside the `for` loop